# How to put LaTeX equation on blender?

Tags: python, text-object

I've been wondering if it is possible to put LaTeX equation in blender like any other text. Does anyone knows how?

Answer (score 2):

"like any other text"?  Not in the sense that you could enter LaTeX into the edit field of a Text object and have it properly formatted, no.  Blender doesn't have a TeX processor built in.

The usual workaround, as seen in the various answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72467/use-latex-in-blender) mentioned in a comment is to use a combination of tools to eventually generate some kind of 2d graphic in a format that Blender can import.  Schematically that means

- Place your LaTeX in a file.
- Use a tool to typeset the LaTex.
- Use a tool to turn the typset LaText into a 2D graphic.
- Use an importer to import the 2D graphic into Blender.
- Bang on the imported graphic in Blender until it is suitable for your purpose.

Updating the answers from the previous question with yet another variation:

- Using MathJax online you can type your LaTex into a form and get an SVG file as a result. [LaTeX to SVG](https://viereck.ch/latex-to-svg/) is one such approach.  This has the small advantage over the approaches in the question that it is OS independent and doesn't require you to install software to process the LaTex.
- Save the SVG file to your computer.
- Use the Import-Export: SVG 1.1 importer to import the SVG file.  This produces a lot of curves.  You may want to convert them to meshes if you want to do things like add textures.
- Done:

[image: an equation]

If you want to process the image further, you may want to install [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), and use it to convert the text to a png file after cleaning it up.  Then you can use *Images as Planes* to import it and not bother with the SVG.